# Share woocomerce products database on different WordPress installs

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

For Share users database on different WordPress installs we use this code:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');
```

Now how can i share products on my other site?